# How do I get a blank column?

Tags: two-column, blank-page

I'm trying to create a program (i.e. the paper kind you hand out) in LaTeX.

I've got `\documentclass[landscape, letterpaper]` and I'm running into problems with the columns. I've tried multicol, minipage, and twocolumn, but I can't get it to do what I want.

```
+-----+-----+
|     |     |
|blank|stuff|
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
```

I want to have the left side blank, and stuff on the right hand side (text on top, image, and text on bottom) all centered on the right side.

When I used twocolumn, I couldn't get the LHS to be blank and put anything on the right side. Minipages seem to completely fail at what I want, simply centering everything on the page.

I haven't been able to find any template to do what I want, because searching for "LaTeX program template" provides me all sorts of results that do not what I need. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, landscape,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vfill
\clearpage
\newpage
    \begin{center}
        \textit{December 8, 2012}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Produces this:
[image: wrong side!]

I want that to appear on the right hand side.

Comment: Will content have to flow over multiple pages?

Comment: No, I'll have distinct content on each "page"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following probably does what you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}                           % Makes the page margins smaller to a predefined one.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
                                                % Added a few parameters to play around with
\columnseprule=0.4pt                            % Adds a rule for aesthetics.
\columnsep=2cm                                  % Increases the width that separates the column.
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{red}} % Changes the default \normalcolor of the column separation rule.
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\vspace*{\textheight}
\columnbreak
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It appears that multicols doesn't work like that right out of the box with landscape mode. But using `\vspace{0.5\textheight}` worked!

Answer (score 5):

For distinct content on a per-page basis, you can also use a `tabular` environment. [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) is also an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
  & \lipsum[1-3]
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Two differences between an approach like this and using a regular `twocolumn` layout would include

1. A vertical rule between columns that might be used as a booklet/pamphlet divider would only stretch as far as the text is printed within the table since it's bound to the `tabularx` structure;
2. Content flow from on page to the next is prohibited.

[`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) would also be capable of managing a layout out like.

Answer (score 3):

While this is old, here is another solution. Instead of leaving a column blank you could simply adjust the margins for a one column document. While this potentially has some undesired side effects, I found this straight forward for multipage documents. The settings below just give a bigger margin to one side for comments. Add the following in your preamble:

```
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{1in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{3in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-4in}
```

Comment: Works fine for me, and is straightforward to adjust to the perfect width. Thanks :)