# Two columns: one column for questions; the other for answers

Tags: vertical-alignment, exam

I am using the `exam` class.

```
\documentclass{12pt,a3paper,landscape}{exam}
```

I would like to split my paper into two columns.  One column should be for the question and across from that question would give the question # and space to solve it.

I have read the question [How do I get a blank column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86113/how-do-i-get-a-blank-column), but not sure how to add the questions in.  Do I just type all my questions after the `&`?

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask after such a long time, but did you ever find a solution?  I ask because I'm having a little difficulty envisioning the goal.  If you still need it, would you perhaps draw a picture of what you'd like it to look like?

Comment: @SeanAllred honestly, I just gave up on it, I just wanted to make a  nice exam for the students, because the school prints everything on   A4 paper, so I thought if I did two collums then I could have the answers to the right of the questions, instead on a different page.

Comment: As a student, God bless your caring heart.  I'm still kinda curious if this can be done though *tinkertinker*

Comment: Such a layout is possible without too much additional programming with [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets). If a solution using it instead of `exam` would be welcome I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tweaking might be needed to suit your needs, but I think what follows may be of help.  I've defined a "two-part" environment called `qanda` (for "Question and Answer"), split by a command called `\nextpart`, for each couple of question and answer. You can finetune the space allocated to each answer by using `\mbox{}\vspace{...}` after `\nextpart`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}

\usepackage[showframe,a4paper]{geometry} % change to a3paper if needed
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtoggle{morethanoneparagraph}
\togglefalse{morethanoneparagraph}

\newcommand{\mycolumnwidth}{0.45\textwidth}

\newenvironment{qanda}{% Q&A
    \newcommand\nextpart{%
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\mycolumnwidth}
        \iftoggle{morethanoneparagraph}{%
            \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*.,resume*=q] 
                \item
        }{%
            \global\toggletrue{morethanoneparagraph}
            \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*.,series=q] 
                \item
        }
    }
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\mycolumnwidth}
    \iftoggle{morethanoneparagraph}{
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,resume*=a] 
            \item 
    }{
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,series=a] 
            \item 
    }
}{
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{qanda}
Prove or disprove $P=NP$
\nextpart \mbox{}\vspace{5cm}
\end{qanda}


\begin{qanda}
Solve
\[
    x^2-x+1=0\,.
\]
\nextpart
\mbox{}\vspace{6cm}
\end{qanda}

\begin{qanda}
Disprove Fermat's Last Theorem.
\nextpart
``Mrs Wiles\ldots please get your husband on the phone\ldots''
\end{qanda}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, I have done that.  its a great answer.