# Question and answer two columns

Tags: two-column, exam

I have searched the internet and found similar things but not an exact one. I want to create environments and other stuff required to make a pdf file as in the image. First comes the subsection title with numbering (④窒素 in the picture), and then the problems and corresponding answers (numberd like (1) and others in the picture) with the same height in both columns. Problems have a checkbox in front of them. The dotted lines in the image appear when a new subsection appears. Preferably, outside the two columns, I want to add a section title like "Introductory Chemistry". And the color of the answer except the numbering
should be red.

Which packages do you suggest using?
[image: The design]

I've tried [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86496/two-columns-one-column-for-questions-the-other-for-answers) but it ended up like

```
\documentclass[landscape,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[showframe,a4paper]{geometry} % change to a3paper if needed
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtoggle{morethanoneparagraph}
\togglefalse{morethanoneparagraph}

\newcommand{\mycolumnwidth}{0.45\textwidth}

\newenvironment{qanda}{% Q&A
    \newcommand\nextpart{%
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\mycolumnwidth}
        \iftoggle{morethanoneparagraph}{%
            \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*.,resume*=q] 
                \item
        }{%
            \global\toggletrue{morethanoneparagraph}
            \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*.,series=q] 
                \item
        }
    }
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\mycolumnwidth}
    \iftoggle{morethanoneparagraph}{
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,resume*=a] 
            \item 
    }{
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,series=a] 
            \item 
    }
}{
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{qanda}
    Find a nonzero polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2\left[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\right]$ which is zero as a function.
    \nextpart
    $x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n \left(x_1+x_2\right)$
\end{qanda}
\begin{qanda}
        Find a nonzero polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ that vanishes at all points of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$
        \nextpart
        $x^p-x$
\end{qanda}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're asking others to build for you a relatively complicated layout. Did you try anything? Are you facing a particular problem? You should add code to your question to show others what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: If you are using `article` class file, then try with the option `twocolumn`, i.e., `\documentclass[...,twocolumn,...]{article}

Comment: The paracol package allows you to synchronize the contents of two columns.  Swapping columns in the middle of enumerate might be tricky.  `\globalcounter*` would help.  The default counter for enumerate (first level) is `enumi`.