# Set right column blank for every page without affecting current template

Tags: two-column, geometry

I want to leave the right side of each page blank for taking notes.

A simple way is to use one-column layout instead and change the right margin,
but using geometry package will affect current template. I'm using

```
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn,]{IEEEtran}
```

After applying geometry package, other margins are changed, ruining the template.

I also tried `\addtolength{\rightmargin}{.3\paperwidth}` without using `geometry` package, but it doesn't change the margin at all.

I also tried `multicols`, but it only leaves the right column of the last page blank.

The template I used can be found [here](https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/use-authoring-tools-and-ieee-article-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-transactions/).

Related questions:

- [Make a two column with one column image and other text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118493/make-a-two-column-with-one-column-image-and-other-text?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How do I get a blank column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86113/how-do-i-get-a-blank-column)
- [A two-column layout with one column dedicated to additional content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340223/a-two-column-layout-with-one-column-dedicated-to-additional-content/340234)

Comment: And what is the problem to set also the left, top and bottom margins with `geometry`?  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)  of how you ruin the template with `geometry` and explain clearly and exactly what you need instead. By the way, the ` IEEEtran` class was designed to submit articles *as is*, not to make your own customs layout to take notes. I would start with a general purpose class as `article` or even the `tufte` class, that by default left a huge right margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IEEEtran class](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) allows commands to override the margins, which you have to pass *before* loading the document class. Here, we have to specify both `\CLASSINPUTinnersidemargin` and `\CLASSINPUToutersidemargin` because if we only specify one, the class symmetrizes the margins by default.

So for the default journal option, this should work:

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTinnersidemargin}{49.27pt}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUToutersidemargin}{5cm} % change to whatever you want
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn,]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

As for how I arrived at that magical number `49.27pt`, I basically ran `\the\dimexpr1in+\oddsidemargin\relax`, and I got this from looking at the page layout (using the `layout` package).

[image]